# How to catch Latios and Latias?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I'm starting to play Pokemon Emerald! How can I catch or encounter Latios or Latias in the game? I want this Pokemon so bad! This is my childhood Pokemon because it can one shot Rayquaza! So cool!

Comment: On Arqade, please try to avoid adding comments like "I really like this", as it does not address the question and is unhelpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latios and Latias can be caught in Hoenn after entering the Hall of Fame. Only one can be found roaming Hoenn, this means it runs around the region, seemingly at random.
The other can be obtained on [Southern Island](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Southern_Island) with the [Eon Ticket](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Eon_Ticket).

Comment: Thanks for this Tip Pinckerman I just got Latios Blue!